# C# Update form contents as list updates

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using C# (WPF) for a project in which people are added to a list; simple enough. However after using a form to add people to the list, I need the main form to "update", for example I want one tabs text to update with the number of people in parenthesis which I would do like this:

```
((TabItem)tabControl.Items[0]).Header = "All Patients ("+ newPatientList.Count.ToString() + ")";
```

This works if the list is populated already, but if I use my form to manually add to the list while the application is running, this wont update on its own.

Pertinent code:
MainWindow, open form to add people to list

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 addPx = new Window1(this);
    addPx.Show();

}
```

Window1, manually add people to list

```
    public MainWindow Main { get; set; }

    public Window1(MainWindow main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Main = main;
    }

   private void adpxbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    if (lstname.Text != string.Empty || frstname.Text != string.Empty || age.Text != string.Empty ||
        rm.Text != string.Empty || status.SelectedValue != null)
    {

        Main.AddNewPatient(lstname.Text, frstname.Text, int.Parse(age.Text), rm.Text, "", int.Parse(status.SelectedItem.ToString()));

        this.Close();
    } else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You're missing some information!");
    }
}
```

So how can I let the mainwindow know to refresh the information? This will become especially useful when I need to display this list and have it autoupdate as people are added/removed from it.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using the correct design pattern for WPF which is MVVM?  I mean, if you want to code imperatively for this framework then the answer to how to update it is the same as for WinForms - tell the control you want to update that it needs to refresh itself.  Apparently that's what Main.AddNewPatient is supposed to do, so start by debugging it since you haven't provided it to us.

Comment: Agree with @hoodaticus that your problem is probably in Main.AddNewPatient. Have you remembered InvokeRequired?

Answer (score 1):

Expose `newPatientList` through a *public property* in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` that you bind to in your XAML. It should be an `ObservableCollection<T>`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Patient> newPatientList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Patient>();
```

You can then bind to its `Count` property in your XAML:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="All Patients (" /><Run Text="{Binding Path=newPatientList.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=OneWay}" /><Run Text=")" />
        </TextBlock>
    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```

...instead of doing this (remove the following from your code):

```
((TabItem)tabControl.Items[0]).Header = "All Patients ("+ newPatientList.Count.ToString() + ")";
```